# NER for predefined entities

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm developing a application to categorize requirements in a requirement specification in to categories like database, front end, back end, etc. Requirement specification is a single document where I want to see the underlying categories in it. Can I use NER to get the categories? Sentences are divided in to categories if they contain certain words that match that particular category.

**Example**

> data should be stored in a secured database.

If we consider above given sentence is a requirement it should be categorized in to database category considering the words it contains (database, data).

Comment: You can train Stanford's NER tagger for your own data and entity but you must have the large dataset for it.

Answer (score 0):

To my best of knowledge, NER pre-built tools would not help, but I recommend you to use [spaCy](https://spacy.io/). It is a NER tools with state-of-the-art accuracy and support re-train your DL model and customize it. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but it requires a lot of data to be trained.

Comment: It depends on what you are looking to do, but you can search for available dataset. I believe that they are somewhere on the Internet.

Comment: I searched for the dataset and even requested it but they are not available. As mentioned in the question I want a dataset which labelled the dataset with the categorizes it belongs like database, front end or back end.

Comment: I am afraid that you could have to make it yourself. However, I have implemented a project to analyze the most important events in a large corpus here. I really think it can help you. https://github.com/yeulam1thienthan/TrendAnalysis-and-IssueTracking-in-NLP
For example, just use clustering to categorize your specifications, then pick the database cluster and pick documents in database cluster. That's my solution for your task.